# DataGridView does not display the cell data

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

The code below when ran does not display the data, do you know what is wrong?

```
DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();

row.SetValues(
    metaData.Offset.ToString("X2"),
    metaData.Length,
    metaData.Format,
    metaData.Description);


dataGridView.Rows.Add(row);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a new `DataGridViewRow`, maybe you can try

```
dataGridView.Rows.Add(metaData.Offset.ToString("X2"),
    metaData.Length,
    metaData.Format,
    metaData.Description);
```

Comment: @MikeAbyss: What does that mean? @Mike: How is this any different than what's posted?

Comment: @Mike yeah it worked, thanks, but what is the reason why the other one did not?